# Script request failed but browser request not

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, coingecko

Which day I can not understand the reason for such a problem.
I'm trying to get data from the Coingecko API in Google App Script.
The simplest script

```js
function ping() {
  var url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping';
  var params = {
    'cache-control': 'public,max-age=300',
    'content-type': 'application/json', 
    'expires': 'Tue,04 Oct 2022 23:59:39 GMT'
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(data);
}
```

gives an error message

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.coingecko.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: {"status":{"error_code":429,"error_message":"You've exceeded the Rate Limit. Please visit https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/pricing to subscribe to ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

But! I immediately enter a request in any browser
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping
And I get a normal response

```
{"gecko_says":"(V3) To the Moon!"}
```

What does this mean and how to deal with it?

Comment: (jsut thinking aloud) API may be counting quota based on IP address. Apps Script's URLFetchApp uses ranges of IPs that shared across all (thousands?) users of Apps Script. Some percent of those users already called URLFetchApp

Comment: Idea is to retry request - until you get lucky IP address that has not reached quota